# Finding row medians (sample medians) of a matrix or dataframe

Tags: r, row, sample, median

I'm trying to find the row medians for a matrix representing 1000 samples of size 30. I've used `rowMeans` and `colMeans` to mean the sample means, but for some reason `rowMedians` and `colMedians` do not work, even after I tried to install various packages. I'm using these values to create density plots of sample means/medians for the exponential(.02) distribution.

```
samp <- matrix(rexp(30000, rate=.02), 30, 1000)
```

This works:

```
sampMeans <- samp %>% rowMeans() %>% data.frame
```

This doesn't:

```
sampMeds <- samp %>% rowMedians() %>% data.frame
```

I also tried:

```
apply(samp, 2, FUN=median)
```

but that was unsuccessful.

Comment: If you want to calculate row wise median you should use `apply(samp, 1, FUN=median) ` also `rowMedians` is from `matrixStats` package, once you load that `samp %>% rowMedians() %>% data.frame` works fine for me.

Comment: For some reason I get this message when trying to install the package: 'install.packages(matrixStats)
Error in install.packages : object 'matrixStats' not found' but the apply function works now. Thanks!

Comment: Try `install.packages('matrixStats')`.